# Mysql query list Roles which has direct relation with specified User OR has Permissions which specified User has at least all of those Permissions

Tags: mysql, query

Assume we have below tables which all of them have n to n relation with each other.

Role Table

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | role 1 |
| 2 | role 2 |
| 3 | role 3 |
| 4 | role 4 |

User Table

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user 1 |
| 2 | user 2 |
| 3 | user 3 |

Permission Table

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | permission 1 |
| 2 | permission 2 |
| 3 | permission 3 |
| 4 | permission 4 |
| 5 | permission 5 |
| 6 | permission 6 |

---

Joining tables are:

Role_User

| id | RoleId | UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |

Role_Permission

| id | RoleId | PermissionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 2 | 6 |

User_Permission

| id | UserId | PermissionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 | 4 |
| 8 | 2 | 5 |
| 9 | 2 | 6 |
| 10 | 3 | 1 |
| 11 | 3 | 2 |
| 12 | 3 | 3 |
| 13 | 3 | 4 |

---

I want to list `Roles`:

1. Which are directly related to `User` by `Role_User` table.
2. Or if has not direct relation with `User`, select which has `Permissions` related by `Role_Permission` that `User` has all of those `Permissions` related by `User_Permission`.

For the above sample data, result will be like blow:

| RoleId | UserId |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |